# Slide Up on Services Pages & Slider Not Working/Showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Originally had this posted in the CSS forums but is a jQuery issue...

Here is the site, if you start off at the homepage, then click on Services in the right navigation it doesn't work the Show Services slideup does not work at all, it should slide up then be able to click a Close button to slide it down...

http://redrhinorestoration.com/wp/

The only time it works is if you go directly to the Services page by typing the URL into your browser, then it will work as you can see how it functions...

http://redrhinorestoration.com/wp/services

Also, having same type of issue on the Process page for my LayerSlider when you start at home page or any other page other than Process then go to Process it doesn't show the slider at all, but if you go directly to Process by typing it in your URL you will see the slider....

http://redrhinorestoration.com/wp/process

Any ideas why this could be? Hopefully that all made sense. To me its like the jquery functions are being disabled or something.

Regards,

Mike

Comment: It has to do with how you are putting your javascript in the pages. The way you currently have your `<script>` elements in the services page they will only be run if the services page is the actively loaded window (i.e. http://redrhinorestoration.com/wp/services). You need to set up your scripts that are unique to each section (page) to execute when that section is clicked on in the page navigation menu as well as when the page loads with that section open.

Comment: Thanks JRulle I see what you mean just not sure to execute this

Comment: Hi JRulle I tried the ajaxComplete function as simpleclick recommended but no success any other ideas what may work?

Comment: What if you write the javascript to open your bottom menu inline in the `onclick=` of the `#showBottom` button? This may not be the ideal long-term solution, but it will help track down where your attachment issues are arising from.

Comment: Thanks JRulle, how exactly would go about this? Is it fairly simple?

Comment: Actually, try this first... in the head of your page there is a `<script>` tag that contains `function inittrans()...`, try editing the next function to be like this: `function onTransitionFinished() { alert("transitioned"); }`

Comment: Ok, did that and I get an alert box popping up when the transition goes

Comment: Okay, I am going to put the code that should go in that function in an answer due to limitations in the comments section.

Comment: Ok, tried it, unfortunately didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing your `onTransitionFinished()` function to handle setting up your buttons for you:

```
function onTransitionFinished()
{
    // alert("transitioned");
    var showBot = $('#showBottom');
    showBot.click(function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuBottom, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
                disableOther( 'showBottom' );
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks JRulle unfortunately this did not work either, this seems to be much more of a difficult issue than expected. Any other ideas?

Comment: First, try moving your `classie.js` script to the `<head>`. Unfortunately, you have a lot of duplicate `<script>` and CSS being added to the page (I think due to the way you slide sections). My advice is try to figure out why your code adds all of these duplicates to the body tag on transition. Last attempt at a quick & dirty fix: add all of the code from your in line (in the body) script tags (that follow the services content) to the above function and see if it is working... I can tell you that function above is intended to set up click areas and things like that after the transition occurs.

Comment: Thanks JRulle appreciate the help alot, hopefully I will find a solutions to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

this is pseudocode. You need to use [$.ajaxComplete();](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) function. this would be triggered after every Ajax call you make on the page

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  showBottom.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuBottom, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
                disableOther( 'showBottom' );
            };

});
```

Comment: Thanks simpleclick...

How exactly do i use this code I'm sorry I'm not very knowledged in jquery or ajax to see how this works I put it in after the function but didnt seem to work, do I need to put this onto every page or just services?

Comment: I also put it into the homepage to see if it worked but no luck, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Still have tried other ways to put this in and still can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to write down javascript code as i mention this is only pseudocode.